# How to test Angular httpClient methods inside a promise in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, httpclient

I know how to test http with a mock backend, as well as promises. Though I am struggling to find a solution to test http methods in a promise. Any advice will be much appreciated. Here's the function which contain the function with the http method inside the promise:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormGroup, FormControl, ValidatorFn, AsyncValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

import { HttpService, IHttpResponse } from '@mystique/mystique-utils/http';
import { IRootState } from '@mystique/mystique-state/root';

@Injectable()
export class ValidatorsService {
  regex: { email: string; password: string } = { email: null, password: null };

  constructor(private _http: HttpService, private _store: Store<IRootState>) {
    this._store.select('config', 'regex').subscribe(regex => (this.regex = regex));
  }

recordExistsOnServer(model: string, lookupField: string, savedValue: string, authToken: string): AsyncValidatorFn {
    model += 's';
    let validationDebounce;

    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      const queryParams = [{ key: lookupField, value: control.value }];

      clearTimeout(validationDebounce);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        validationDebounce = setTimeout(() => {
          if (control.value === '' || control.value === savedValue) {
            return resolve(null);
          }
          this._http.get$(`/${model}`, authToken, queryParams).subscribe((httpResponse: IHttpResponse) => {
            if (!httpResponse.data) {
              savedValue = control.value;
            }
            return !httpResponse.data ? resolve(null) : resolve({ recordExistsOnServer: true });
          });
        }, 400);
      });
    };
  }
```

Throws this error: Uncaught TypeError:

```
_this._http.get$ is not a function at localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:2281
```

Here is my test cases, the last it() fails:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { StoreModule, Store } from '@ngrx/store';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpService } from '@mystique/mystique-utils/http';
import { HttpServiceStub } from '@mystique/mystique-stubs';
import { ValidatorsService } from './validators.service';
import { rootReducer } from '@mystique/mystique-state/root';

describe('ValidatorsService', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                StoreModule.forRoot({
                    config: rootReducer.config
                })
            ],
            providers: [{ provide: HttpService, useClass: HttpServiceStub }, ValidatorsService]
        });
    });

    let service, http, store;
    beforeEach(() => {
        http = TestBed.get(HttpService);
        store = TestBed.get(Store);
        service = TestBed.get(ValidatorsService);
    });

    describe('when checking if a record exists on the server', () => {
        let control, result, getSpy;
        beforeEach(() => {
            getSpy = spyOn(http, 'getAll$');
        });

        it('returns null if the user types the same value', done => {
            control = new FormControl('bob');
            result = service.recordExistsOnServer('user', 'username', 'bob', 'token');
            result(control)['then'](r => {
                expect(r).toEqual(null);
                done();
            });
        });

        it('returns null if the user types an empty string', done => {
            control = new FormControl('');
            result = service.recordExistsOnServer('user', 'username', 'bob');
            result(control)['then'](r => {
                console.log('r: ' + r)
                expect(r).toEqual(null);
                done();
            });
        });

        it('returns null if the http call cannot find a record', done => {
            getSpy.and.returnValue(Observable.of({ data: null }));
            control = new FormControl('bobby');
            result = service.recordExistsOnServer('user', 'username', 'bob');
            result(control)['then'](r => {
                expect(r).toEqual(null);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my http.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { IRootState } from '@mystique/mystique-state/root';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { IBaseModel } from '@spawntech/xmen-core-domain-models';

export interface IHttpQuery {
  key: string;
  value: string | number;
}

export interface IHttpResponse {
  success: boolean;
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
  message: string;
  data?: any | any[];
  error?: string;
  token?: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  apiBaseUrl: string = null;
  httpRetries = 3;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private _store: Store<IRootState>) {
    this._store.select('config', 'apiBaseUrl').subscribe(url => (url ? (this.apiBaseUrl = url) : this.apiBaseUrl));
  }

  get$(restUrl: string, authToken: string, queryParams?: IHttpQuery[]): Observable<IHttpResponse> {
    if (!restUrl) {
      throw new Error('A restful url extension must be supplied');
    }

    const headers = this._prepareAuthHeader(authToken);
    const params = this._prepareQueryParams(queryParams);
    console.log('in http service---------------')
    return this._http
      .get<IHttpResponse>(this.apiBaseUrl + restUrl, { headers, params })
      .retry(this.httpRetries)
      .catch((response: HttpErrorResponse) => this._handleError(response));
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your spec code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Throws this error: Uncaught TypeError: _this._http.get$ is not a function
at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:2281    it('returns null if the http call cannot find a record', done => {
          getSpy.and.returnValue(Observable.of({ data: null }));
          control = new FormControl('bobby');
          result = service.recordExistsOnServer('user', 'username', 'bob');
          result(control)['then'](r => {
            expect(r).toEqual(null);
            done();
          });
        });

Comment: Add that information to the question, please.

Comment: little more information about importing and construct in service file

Answer (score 0):

use HttpClientTestingModule for mock http request

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [..., HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [...]
    })
```

in the development of applications, I call the service method which returns a query, then I subscribe () and I already consider successful and erroneous queries in the current component, displaying some notifications to the user
then you can take a query from a function to a separate function and do something like this:

```
spyOn (service, 'confirmEmail').
       .returnValue (Observable.of (new HttpResponse ({body: '', status: 204}))));
```